# Select same name object with two dimension

Tags: r

Below is the sample data. May I ask how can I select all `ge_v` at once? If there is only single number inside [], I know I can use `sprintf ('ge_v[%d]', seq(10))` to select ge_v[1]...ge_v[10]. How can I do the same thing for two dimensional data?

```
structure(list(rn = c("ge_v[27,1]", "ge_v[28,2]", "ge_v[29,3]", 
"ge_v[30,4]", "ge_v[31,5]", "ge_v[32,6]", "ge_v[33,7]", "ge_v[34,8]", 
"ge_v[35,9]", "ge_v[36,10]", "ge_v[37,11]"), mean = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c("70", "71", "72", "73", 
"74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Did you meant `sprintf ('ge_v[%d, %d]', seq(10), seq(10))`

Comment: Or if it is the same argument, you can use `sprintf('ge_v[%1$d,%1$d]', seq(10))`

Comment: oh! Thank you. I did something similar but apparently something wrong when I was trying!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this helps

```
sprintf ('ge_v[%d,%d]', 27:36, 1:10)
```

Comment: sorry to bother you again. Can I make it to select, for example ,`ge_v[1, ]`, everything with the first number as a certain number?

Comment: @Shepard In that case, you just need `sprintf('ge_v[%d,]', 1)`

Comment: What I was trying to do is to filter data to select all `ge_v`, can I do that without specifying what is inside `[ ]`?

Comment: @Shepard What is your expected output as it is not clear from the input data.  In the input data, all the rows in `rn` column have `ge_v`

Comment: `sprintf ('ge_v[%d,%d]', 1:40, 15:188)` (this is not work as arguments cannot be recycled to the same length), this is what I was trying to filter. I have 40 subjects and 188-15 trials, so in total 40*(188-15) `ge_v`, and I was trying to filter them out from the data.

Comment: @Shepard I think you need to use `expand.grid` i.e. .`do.call(sprintf, c(fmt = 'ge_v[%d,%d]', expand.grid(1:40, 15:188)))`